# How to make PIVOT a table / Cross tab query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made a `SELECT` statement to get this output:

```
MOVIE                           Critic Type  Average Rating
------------------------        ------------ --------------
30 Minutes or Less              Critic                 2.00
30 Minutes or Less              User                   4.20
A Lonely Place to Die           Critic                10.00
A Lonely Place to Die           User                   8.50
Taken                           Critic                 6.17
Taken                           User                   7.27
Taken 2                         Critic                 4.00
Taken 2                         User                   6.29

8 rows selected
```

Here is the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT MovieTitle AS "MOVIE", TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC AS "Critic Type", AVG(TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR) AS "Average Rating"
FROM TBLMOVIE 
INNER JOIN TBLREVIEW ON TBLMOVIE.MOVIEID = TBLREVIEW.MOVIEID 
INNER JOIN TBLCRITIC ON TBLREVIEW.CRITICID = TBLCRITIC.CRITICID 
INNER JOIN TBLCRITICCLASS ON TBLCRITIC.CRITICCLASSID = TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSID 
GROUP BY MovieTitle, TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC
ORDER BY Movietitle;
```

I want to turn this table into this output with a `PIVOT` to get the output with the critic rating and user rating as it's own category:

```
MOVIE                           Critic Rating   User Rating
------------------------        -------------   -----------
30 Minutes or Less              2.00                   4.20
A Lonely Place to Die           10.00                  8.50
Taken                           6.17                   7.27
Taken 2                         4.00                   6.29
```

My attempt to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT MovieTitle AS "MOVIE", AVG(TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR) AS "Critic Rating", AVG(TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR) AS "User Rating"
  FROM TBLMOVIE 
  INNER JOIN TBLREVIEW ON TBLMOVIE.MOVIEID = TBLREVIEW.MOVIEID 
  INNER JOIN TBLCRITIC ON TBLREVIEW.CRITICID = TBLCRITIC.CRITICID 
  INNER JOIN TBLCRITICCLASS ON TBLCRITIC.CRITICCLASSID = TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSID 
  GROUP BY MovieTitle, TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC
  ORDER BY Movietitle
)

PIVOT
(
  AVG(TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR) AS "Critic Rating"
  FOR TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR IN (TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC)

  AVG(TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR) AS "User Rating"
  FOR TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR IN (TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC)
)
```

I get errors, It's probably due to my lack of skill with subqueries, I would like to understand why I am not getting my preferred output and how to fix it.

EDIT:

Here are the tables associated:

[File1 (Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/yCmYPtAC)

[File2 (Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/etWUTC63)

Comment: Several things...  `PIVOT` is already an aggregate function (like `GROUP BY` and then `select AVG(...)`), so you don't need to group and take averages before you pivot; the `AVG()` can be done when you pivot. Then, don't even `ORDER BY` in a subquery; the only `ORDER BY`, if needed, should be in the outer query. Finally, the `PIVOT` syntax isn't right - @xQbert shows how to do it in his Answer. If you will add to your Question to show table names and columns, we can help you write your current query and the PIVOT all in one statement. (I could guess from your current attempt, but I won't.)

Comment: I have added the tables into a pastebin link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have your pivot statement wrong.  You could substitute your query for the CTE below and it should work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT MovieTitle AS "MOVIE"
           , TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC AS      "Critic Type"
           , AVG(TBLREVIEW.REVIEWSTAR) AS "Average Rating"
      FROM TBLMOVIE 
      INNER JOIN TBLREVIEW 
        ON TBLMOVIE.MOVIEID = TBLREVIEW.MOVIEID 
      INNER JOIN TBLCRITIC 
        ON TBLREVIEW.CRITICID = TBLCRITIC.CRITICID 
      INNER JOIN TBLCRITICCLASS 
        ON TBLCRITIC.CRITICCLASSID = TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSID 
      GROUP BY MovieTitle, TBLCRITICCLASS.CRITICCLASSDESC
      )
PIVOT (AVG("Average Rating") for "Critic Type" 
   in ('Critic' as "Critic Rating", 'User' as "User Rating")))
ORDER BY Movie
```

As to, "Why I am not getting my preferred output"

You are piviting on "Critic Type" for which you have two values ('critic' and user')  the aggregrate `avg` makes sense; but in your example you only have 1 value for each record so min/max would work as well.

In a pivot you specify each column in the "in" portion of the pivot, letting the DB engine determine how to orgainze the data based on the values in the "Critic Type" column.

Because you have to specify each value, you can't have a dynamic range, without dynamic SQL.

Note: you can alias the columns in the "IN" portion of the pivot if you desire different names than the values in the "for" pivot field.

[image]

Comment: Any way to do it in a similar manner that I used as an example (with subqueries?) I'm not familiar with CTE.

Comment: I incorporated your Query into the pivot.  There likely is a more efficient way of doing this without the overhead of 2 queries; I just don't have time to address that level of detail at the moment.